# How to move Redash hostservice to my ec2? Migration script is not working

Tags: redash

Redash is discontinuing their hosting service app.redash.io/****. I follow [this doc](https://redash.io/help/open-source/setup) to standup an AWS EC2 instance from opensource AMI. First, redash-toolbelt seems installed but can't find redash-migrate. Then I cloned the repo and checked out the issue-5. The recommended [migration](https://github.com/getredash/redash-toolbelt/pull/23) is not working for this AMI. pip install cannot find peotry.

```
$ pip3 install peotry
Collecting peotry
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement peotry (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for peotry
```

Is there a better way to migrate all my data from Redash site to my EC2? (backup & restore) I do not have CLI access to the Redash hosting site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you've made a typo. It should be `pip install poetry`. What you have written is peotry.